# Gauss' law not considering excess charge

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

I am trying to understand Gauss' law but do not understand this part -- does Gauss' law not consider excess charge (outside the Gaussian surface)?

In a system where we are using a Gaussian surface, and the excess charge is distributed asymmetrically, is Gauss' Law then not a good tool to use to estimate the electric field?

Note: I understand that in a symmetric distribute of excess charge, it will all cancel out. Also, I am not wondering about charged conductors. I just want to know how Gauss' Law works for a Gaussian surface.

Comment: Determining the electric field using Gauss' law by integrating over Gaussian surfaces will not be useful in general, only in symmetrical cases. If you are studying electromagnetism you will discover more advanced methods later in your studies.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "excess charge"? Do you mean net charge? Second, Gauss' law applies to net enclosed charge, not outside the Gaussian surface.

Comment: @BobD: By excess charge I mean the charge outside the closed surface. If Gauss' Law only applies to net enclosed charge, does that mean it is not useful if there is a significant external charge that affects the electric field (and is not considered by Gauss' Law)?

Comment: @MikeSmith all the flux entering the volume leaves the volume so the external charge does not effect the net flux across the Gaussian surface

Comment: Yes, I was confused by the distance aspect, which doesn't end up mattering as I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main questions here.

1. Gauss's law says that the net electric flux through a closed surface due to a charge $q$ is $\Phi_E = q/\epsilon_0$ if the charge lies inside the surface, and $\Phi_E = 0$ if the charge lies outside the surface.  So Gauss's Law does "account for" both charges inside and outside the surface, in the sense that it gives an accurate result whether or not there are additional charges outside the surface.  The reason that there is no net flux from a charge outside the surface is that such a charge gives rise to equal amounts of positive flux on one portion of the surface and negative flux on other portions of the surface.
2. Gauss's Law is generally not useful for finding the electric field at any particular point unless you have a high degree of symmetry and use a Gaussian surface that conforms to that symmetry.  Gauss's law tells you the net electric flux, which is in some sense a "net number of field lines" going through a surface.  But knowing the total number of field lines going through a surface doesn't tell you anything about how those field lines are distributed over the surface, which is (roughly) what you need to know to find the actual electric field.  Only when you have some other information about the distribution of the field lines (i.e., they're uniformly distributed over the surface due to the symmetry of the situation) can you use Gauss's Law to find the electric field.

Comment: I guess my question is really just why electric flux does not depend on a distance r from the Gaussian surface despite it being the integration of the dot product of electric field (which depends on distance) and dA (surface area).

Comment: @MikeSmith:  Suppose we have a surface enclosing a charge.  If the surface is small, then the area of the surface is small but the electric field is large.  If the surface is large, then the area of the surface is large but the electric field is small.  The flux is (effectively) the product of the area and the electric field, and the increase in the surface area is perfectly balanced by the decrease in the electric field, yielding the same flux no matter what you do.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much, this clears it up intuitively. Is there a way to formally prove this?

Comment: @MikeSmith:  The "best" formal proof (IMO) involves vector calculus and the divergence theorem.   But for a somewhat more intuitive and geometric proof, see Section 1.10 of Purcell & Morin, *Electricity and Magnetism*.